# How to use FieldGroupings in Storm

Tags: apache-storm

In bolt I have below records
   bolt1 -> (id , dept , salary)   Assume running task is 6

Next bolt has to receive the data based on the id. could anyone give me the sample code, how to use fieldGrouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
builder.addSpout("spout" new MySpout());
builder.addBolt("bolt1", new Bolt1()).shuffleGrouping("spout"); // Bolt1 emits (id, dept, salary)
builder.addBolt("bolt2", new Bolt2()).fieldsGrouping("bolt1", new Fields("id"));
```